# How to: Change UIModalPresentationStyle from .automatic to .fullscreen for a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, ios13, uimodalpresentationstyle

I attempted to set `modalPresentationStyle` to .fullscreen following the Apple Documentation.

After setting the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullscreen` shown in the code below, the system still presents the viewControllers in `UIModalPresentationStyle.automatic` "the system default"

```
//Presentation Style
let homeVC = HomeController(viewModel: viewModel)
homeVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
```

A framework called XCoordinator controls navigation within this application, here is an example on how it is done.

```
switch route { 
case .home: 

let viewModel = HomeViewModelImpl(router: anyRouter) 
let viewController = HomeController(viewModel: viewModel) 

return .push(viewController)

}
```

Comment: Define "not working". [Edit] your question with more specific details.

Comment: @rmaddy updated

Comment: are you sure it'snot being set in a storyboard / xib ?

Comment: @NitinAlabur Yep! The project uses view controllers created programmatically , the storyboard is not in play here

Comment: Are you presenting `homeVC` itself or a view controller that contains `homeVC` (like a navigation controller, for example)? What does your code look like where you do the actual presentation?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler views are pushed on the stack using a framework called XCoordinator like so

`switch route {
    case .home:
      let viewModel = HomeViewModelImpl(router: anyRouter)
      let viewController = HomeController(viewModel: viewModel)
      
      return .push(viewController)`

Comment: I've never used XCoordinator but taking a quick look at the documentation and I see `.push` will just push it onto the navigation stack so I doubt that will ever be modal.  I suggest maybe looking into `.present` instead.  As I said I haven't used it but that would be my guess.  Whichever way you look at it though you have given control of presentation over to XCoordinator so the issue lies there.

Comment: @Joshua Do not put details in comments. Please [edit] your question with all relevant details.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated

Comment: @rmaddy Updated the question with the details, sorry about that .

Answer (score 0):

The `TabBarCoordinator` has a rootViewController when XCoordinator is setup.

The solution here was to set the `.modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullscreen` off of the `rootViewController` .

`rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullscreen`

Please *note* this has to be called after any `super` method in your class file